# Converting higher-order ODE to first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given
$$
y''' + 2y'' -5y' = 2y + 5y^3
$$
convert to a system of first order equations.

My question is do we need to make substitutions for $y$ and $y^3$ or are we only concerned with the derivatives, if so then let $x_{1} = y$, $x_{2} = y'$, $x_{3} = y''$ then we get $x_1' = x_2$, $x_2' = x_3$, $x_3' = 5x_2 - 2x_3 + 2y + 5y^3$ but this doesn't have the same form of other similar problems I've solved. Do I let $x_4 = y$ and $x_5 = y^3$ or do I leave the y's in since they aren't derivatives?

Comment: Only $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Comment: I thought the order of the equation was determined by the highest derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first equation gives you the substitution for (renaming of) $y$.

$x_1=y$ so you just need to set $y=x_1$ and $y^3=(x_1)^3$ to get your system only in terms of $x_1, x_2, x_3$.